# Mac Automator/AppleScript: Is there a way to refer to Variables within AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I've seen a lot of questions about this on the interwebs but no answers. Is there a way to refer to an Automator 'variable' within AppleScript? I'd like to do some string manipulation as part of a workflow. I've worked around this by using Get Variable and passing them into temporary files, but it's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AppleScript used in a workflow accepts two parameters: `input`, or the output of the previous workflow, and `parameters`, the options set in the workflow's UI (if applicable). If the string you are manipulating is part of the workflow's input, it will be in `input`.

More information is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ImplementScriptAction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001512-CJBJEJBE).

Comment: Thanks. Based on your reply, I tried dumping 'parameters' (with 'return parameters'), and it had interesting things in it, but did not contain the automator 'variable' I had set with 'Set Value of Variable'.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying the same ting as Steven. My conclusion is that when you run a flow inside the "Automator" application then your applescript can access Automator-varaibles via the Apple Script "Automator Suite" interface. For example:

```
set my_variable to value of variable "The Variable" of workflow 0 of current application
display dialog my_variable as text
set my_variable to "Test"
```

But if you save the flow as a stand alone application then it does NOT include the "Automator Suite" into the application and therefore the above script will no longer function :-(

Comment: thanks for the update! That sounds promising, but also sounds sort of not fully baked.  I'll with it when I next work with Automator…